# Directory of URL Schemes for Mac Apps

Tags: macos, url

Is there a directory of all the Mac Apps that support URL Schemes? A URL Scheme is a custom url that launches the app and might perform an action.

```
omnifocus://
```

The above URL scheme works for OmniFocus.app

Comment: Are you looking which apps support which URI schemes on *your* machine, or a general listing?

Comment: @slhck Let's assume the former, as the latter isn't possible given that there is no list of *all the Mac Apps* to begin with. Versiontracker/MacUpdate might be *reasonably* complete though. It would help a lot if this question contained some information about the motivation.

Comment: I was primarily looking for a general listing, but finding the apps on my machine would be useful as well.

Answer (score 15):

Another option would be to use `lsregister -dump`.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -B6 bindings:.*:`

Comment: Thank you, the long command worked.

Answer (score 9):

For a list of all URL schemes the applications on your system support, get [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). It will add a preference pane to system preferences that includes a list of supported URL schemes and the applications providing that support.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Please note that these schemes are not necessarily related to useful services provided by the apps. Many exist simply to facilitate registering software (e.g. `x-voodoopad-register`, `x-unison2-reg`,or `webnote-license`) by clicking a link in an email and aren't of any use otherwise. For the rest, you need to figure out how to use them. Just running e.g. `open txmt://foo` in the Terminal will not produce a useful result.

[image: Screenshot]