# How do I reveal a file in Finder based on file:// URL?

Tags: macos, finder

I am building a webpage that indexes files on my system (macOS). I would like to be able to add two hyperlinks to each file, one which a) opens the file, and one which b) reveals the file in the finder.

Regarding a), I can open a file with the following URL:

```
file://…
```

However, this displays it in the browser window, whereas I would prefer to open it in the default application. So not quite what is needed.

Regarding b), I have no idea if such a URL scheme exists, but would appreciate it if anyone knows how to achieve this.

I have been able to achieve it by passing the file path to Keyboard Maestro and then using a macro to open / reveal the file. However, I would prefer to achieve this without any intermediate application.

Comment: Ah, that edit changes everything. You can list URL schemes with [`lsregister -dump`](http://superuser.com/q/498943/). You may be able to create a custom handler based on [this question and its answers](http://superuser.com/q/548119/). Maybe [this](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001154.html) works for you? (Please reply with @slhck)

Answer (score 1):

The file:// path is generally just file:// and then the files path.

One way to do it in Finder is to **right-click the file then press "Get Info", or select the file and Command + I** (shortcut) to bring up the files information.

**You can find the file's path next to "Where:" (under General). You can just copy that** (Command + C *or* Edit > Copy) and paste that (don't worry, it will be copied as a UNIX path (e.g */users/Name/My Folder*)

Now, in your browser you can just type: **file://(paste in the path you copied)/files name**

*edit: Someone edited your question so now i'm not too sure what your intention is.*

Comment: This is the original question of the author: http://superuser.com/revisions/1176559/1 – I guess your answer refers to the "wrong" interpretation.